# Hosting MVC4 on IIs, IE Jquery not defined

Tags: c#, jquery, internet-explorer, asp.net-mvc-4

I have troubles hosting my MVC4 Razor Page on an IIS.

IE throws Javascript Exceptions telling me that JQuery is undefined.

Firefox, Chrome and safari however yield the expected results. 
IE only does when I run the page in Visual Studio.

I allready added Json2 to the loaded bundles, but it doesnt make any difference.

This is the Error I get (translated from german), strangely it says useragent mozilla, eventough im using IE:

```
Benutzer-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
Timestamp: Thu, 27 Jun 2013 08:56:40 UTC


Message: "jQuery" ist undefined
Line: 3
Position: 9
Code: 0
URI: {I truncated this part}
```

More Errordetails:

```
Benutzer-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0; .NET4.0E; .NET4.0C; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.30729)
TimeStamp: Fri, 28 Jun 2013 06:22:20 UTC


Message: The property "parse" is undefined or a nullreference cannot be accessed.
Row: 1
Position: 11360
Code: 0
URI: http://{truncated}/bundles/jquery?v=QT-MfBNWG6RxlNLKR_LlaTqXz7sanlWZtuzFZWf9Q241


Message: The Property or Value "$" is Null or undefined, no functionobject.
Row: 1
Position: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://{truncated}/bundles/sog?v=uOX6wPLh-TeIee9Arm9jRzamg1YMj7_AD14EPlYUAag1
```

Comment: User-Agent from IE is Mozilla as nearly from every browser. Use F12 Tools to debug and see if jquery has been loaded. jQuery 2.x is not available for IE7 btw.

Comment: Im not sure what to check in F12.I provided a few more error detais. How come it works fine in Visual Studio but not when hosted on IIs, i dont get it :/

Comment: @CSharpie, it doesn't work because in IIS you are running in Release mode and thus your Bundles are actually minifying and combining your scripts. So if you have errors in your bundle definitions that would explain.